# Count the number of products inside a post

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called "collection" and every post under it has a shortcode **[woocommmerce-list]**, this displays products with a particular taxonomy, need help guys, thanks

**For example**

```
Leather Bags - this displays 4 products inside that post
Denim Bags - this display 6 products inside that post
Plastic Bags - this displays 8 products inside that post
```

**So when I made a loop:**

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'collection',
    'order'    => (isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC'),
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    echo the_title();
    echo ' - ';
    echo $loop->post_count;

    endwhile;

endif;
```

**Current results:**

```
Leather Bags - 3
Denim Bags - 3
Plastic Bags - 3
```

**Result should be like this**

```
Leather Bags - 4
Denim Bags - 6
Plastic Bags - 8
```

**I found a solution**

on my shortcode I added

```
$found = $products->post_count;
```

and then I added a custom field using ACF on every post and added this code

```
update_field('total_number_of_products', $found);
```

then on the title I add this

```
get_field( 'total_number_of_products', $post_id );
```

it shows the correct number of products but now the problem is it only updated when the post is loaded and it only shows the first page total number, how can I make this automatic to all

Comment: the_title(); is used to display the post name so where is the taxonomy ?

Comment: yes, I am displaying posts from a custom post type and inside those post is a shortcode that displays woocommerce products, I just need to count the products and display the number beside the post title

Comment: Current loop's post_count is about current posts i.e.  3 in this case. To know how many products are being fetched by the shortcode you need to go beyond current loop. Maybe edit your shortcode which also include #of posts fetched above the markup ...

Comment: found a solution but please see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    echo the_title();

    echo ' - ';

    $children = get_pages('child_of='. get_the_ID() );

    echo count( $children );

    endwhile;

endif;
```